# Programatically Created Files of the Same Type and Name

Tags: java, ftp, filesystems

How did my application manage to upload (to an FTP server) duplicates of files of the same names and types, instead of overwriting the first file?

```
2012-11-09.log      52  Text Document       11/9/2012 8:44:00 PM        -rw-rw-r--
2012-11-09.log      49  Text Document       11/9/2012 8:41:00 PM        -rw-rw-r--
2012-11-09.log      59  Text Document       11/9/2012 8:44:00 PM        -rw-rw-r--
2012-11-09.log      53  Text Document       11/9/2012 8:41:00 PM        -rw-rw-r--
2012-11-09.log      57  Text Document       11/9/2012 8:40:00 PM        -rw-rw-r--
```

There’s nothing special about how I’m writing to the FTP server. Here is a Java snippet:

```
String dest = "ftp://[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]@[FTP].com/DR/"+Util.putDateStamp() + ".log";
u = new URL(dest);
uc = u.openConnection();
uc.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream outgoing = uc.getOutputStream();

outgoing.write(dataToSend.getBytes());
outgoing.close();
```

I am not able to rename or delete the files, because it throws the error “file not found”. My effort to reproduce it unfortunately behaved as expected – it wrote over the first file of the same name.So, I haven’t been able to reproduce the error. Keep in mind I have limited permissions on the FTP server. It is not mine. My last resort is to tell the admin I corrupted it somehow. It’s not a big deal, but not knowing how it happened really bothers me.
I realize there is an FTP command for renaming files when they are not unique, but that’s not the issue.

My question is: How did this happen, and since I cannot reproduce it, how can I avoid doing it again?

Code from Util:

```
public static String putDateStamp(){
    String currentdate = "";
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    currentdate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    return currentdate;
}
```

**Edit:**

Server OS: UNIX Type: L8

Comment: My guess is, the difference is not readily apparent to you, but there is one.  Perhaps a trailing space in the filename, or a capitalization change which isn't immediately evident.

Comment: But the same code was used to create all 3 files...

Comment: No OS allows you to create multiple files of the same name in the same directory.  There is a difference, but we simply can't visually see what the difference is.
what kind of OS is the server running?  how are you getting the listing?  

Also, if you rename it (them) in one command via FTP (from '2012-11-09.log" to "abc"), does it rename all of them, or just one of them?

Comment: if you try to rename the files and you get a "no such file or directory" it's because you're not giving the right name. You're giving the name you see, which is not the name it is. There's a character in the filenames which is unprintable via whatever means you're printing the names. It may be time to show us the source for Util.putDateStamp() to see if there's any way it generates a String containing a strange character

Comment: When I try to rename them, I get a "No such file or directory". The listing is created with the "LIST" command. I understand that's how the OS is supposed to work. If I had access to it, I would check the node IDs, and they'd (hopefully) be different. Hold on, I'm going to edit my original post with server details...

Comment: I would typically use a shell (tcsh or bash) to do tab-completion on the filenames, showing me the difference between the names.  Or, a command like (BE CAREFUL) "rm -i *": the -i will prompt you for each name, and put quotes around the names showing spaces, and escaping the unprintable characters in the filenames, which shows you the difference between filenames 'f', 'f<space>' and 'f<tab>'.  Do you have cmdline access to the server?

Comment: It's just a regular old unicode string, produced the same way for each file. Copy/pasting the filename to use in a DELE command has the same effect as using Filezilla to delete it.

Comment: No I don't have command line access, otherwise I'd be looking at node IDs... I think it's time to tell the sysadmin there's something wrong. If he doesn't know how to use command line to delete it, I will certainly do some investigating myself. Thank you for pointing out that the names might have a strange character, it's not somthing I thought of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - basically Filezilla does not allow escaping spaces in file names, and also doesn't display the spaces. So the custom command `DEL "     filename.log"` throws file-not-found errors.

The files had varying numbers of spaces before their names, probably entered in the form after using JDatePicker.

The files were deleting using a different FTP client.